# how to sort specific payment method in 1st place in checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, onestepcheckout

how to sort specific payment method in 1st place in checkout page in magento where i want  PPG as 1st option which is not having sort order field

Comment: For all other method set sort order greater than 0 and check if your method comes in a first place or not if no then try to set greater than 1

Answer (score 1):

Define `<sort_order>0</sort_order>` inside **config.xml** or create Admin option for `<sort_order>` inside system/config using module's **system.xml**